# How to use mouse position to determine text colour

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm trying to have the RGB value of some text on a page in Lay theme (wordpress) determined by the position of the mouse. I've currently got this working to change the background colour (see below) but want it to change text colour instead. Ideally the colour of all text but I could do it individually.

Also would be nice to have it based on the position of the mouse on the screen, rather than on the page.

Thanks

```
<script>
    ( function( $ ) {
        'use strict';
        $( document ).on( 'ready', function() {
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        var $width = ($(document).width())/255;
        var $height = ($(document).height())/255;
        var $pageX = parseInt(e.pageX / $width,10);
        var $pageY = parseInt(e.pageY / $height,10);
        var $pageXY = ($pageX+$pageY)/2;
        $("body").css("background-colour", "rgb("+$pageY+","+$pageXY+",255)");
        });
        } );
    } ( jQuery ) );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp) "The color property is used to set the color of the text. The color is specified by:

- a color name - like "red"
- a HEX value - like "#ff0000"
- an RGB value - like "rgb(255,0,0)"

". Try this:

```
$("body").css("color", "rgb("+$pageY+","+$pageXY+",255)");
```

If the text element (div or other) has a class with `color` property then the style will not cascade to the text. You should select the text element instead of `body`.

I tried this and it works:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head/>
<body>
    <div id='textId' style='color: red'>
     text
    </div>
    <div id='button' style="height: 300px;width: 200px; background-color: red;"></div>
    <script>
     document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
         $("#textId").css("color", "rgb(255,55,255)");
     });
    </script>

<body/>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi kodvin, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the text colour isn't changing still, I wonder whether I need to reference the class at all?

Comment: try this `$("body *")..css("color", "rgb("+$pageY+","+$pageXY+",255)");` if it works i will update the answer. But what i suspect is that you have added a color for that text element. You should select the text directly by class or id reference instead of selecting body(or use the  start * to select everything)

Comment: Yeah I think its the fact that Lay theme already sets a colour for it automatically, just trying to work out how to refer to the element in the code. I've tried replacing the 'body' with "fixed-element" (the class I have assigned to that block of text but no luck. I think it muse be being over-rided elsewhere or something